# How to remove version information from the static files of magento

Tags: magento2

Version information for the static content can even be seen in the developer mode.

like

```
pub/static/version1536693046/frontend
```

Useful for varnish or other cache but painful while server returns the particular version could not be found.

Answer (score 1):

This can be turned off updating the core_config_data quickly, then cleaning and clearing magento cache.

```
mysql> select * from `core_config_data` where path =  'dev/static/sign';
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------+-------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path            | value |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------+-------+
|        82 | default |        0 | dev/static/sign | 1     |
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> update core_config_data set value = 0 where config_id = 82;
```

Other method is going to  **Stores > System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Static Files Settings** from magento admin login as suggested by magento 2 guide. [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cache/static-content-signing.html).

Cache should be cleared in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily turn this off with the following CLI command:

```
bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 0
```